# Can't use corr2cov function in MATLAB R2013B

Tags: matlab, function, std, covariance, correlation

i type

> covariances = corr2cov(STDs , correlations)

matlab says

> Undefined function 'corr2cov' for input arguments of type 'double'.

i typed

> which corr2cov

it said

> 'corr2cov' not found.

Dunno what to do, please help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: CORR2COV is in the Financial Toolbox, not a pert of "core" MATLAB.  Does the installation you're working with include that toolbox?

Comment: I checked that with "ver" command, and saw that it wasn't installed. I had checked all the toolboxes in the installation window tho. Reinstalled it 2 minutes ago, everything works like a charm. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!
P.S. I'm new to MatLab (building efficient frontlines of portfolios) :)